# request.getSession is not returning same session

Tags: java, session, servlets, spring-mvc

Our product is developed in Spring 3.0 MVC.

We have used, session as follows in controllers.

```
  @Controller
  public class LoginController{
     HttpSession session;

     @RequestMapping(value="/index.htm",method = RequestMethod.POST)
     public ModelAndView viewIndex(HttpServletRequest request){
     session=request.getSession(false);
     System.out.println(request.getSession(false));
     System.out.println(session);   
     }
  }
```

Here in Firefox, i can see both `request.getSession(false)` and `session` are printed with same value.

While in IE, i can see `request.getSession(false)` prints a value and `session` is printed as `null`.

What could be the reason?

Note: I am not using any filter for session

Comment: Assigning the session to a field of your controller is a very bad idea, you're just asking for weird concurrency issues.  Get rid of that, and make sure your problem still occurs when just using local variables.

Answer (score 10):

You should **never** assign request or session specific variables as a field of a class of which there's only one instance throughout the entire application's lifetime. All the webpage visitors would then share the same variable. Visitor X would then share the session with visitor Y. This is a huge data integrity leak.

As to grabbing the session, if you *need* the session, just use `request.getSession()` straight without the boolean. Do *not* assign it to some field for "later reuse".

```
@RequestMapping(value="/index.htm",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView viewIndex(HttpServletRequest request){
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    // ... Get/set attributes?
}
```

For more background information about how servlets works under the covers (Spring MVC is a framework which is built on top of the basic Servlet API), you may find this post useful: [How do servlets work? Instantiation, sessions, shared variables and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/java-servlet-instantiation-and-session-variables/3106909#3106909).